# How do you delete an empty array from javascript?

Tags: javascript

For reference I have zero javascript knowledge or any coding knowledge. I typically just hook up applications via IPASS applications that don't require any coding knowledge. However, I found out I need to inject some javascript into the application in order to avoid an error message.

I have the below JSON record.

I need to get rid of the empty array (sorry... if it is not an array but an object? Like I said, no javascript knowledge).

In the below code essentially what I want is to completely delete this line, because there is nothing inside the brackets and it is causing errors:

"lineitemsdata": []

Full JSON record below for reference

```
  "id": "5399286500",
  "properties": {
    "state": "AB",
    "website": null,
    "zip": "T3B5Y9"
  },
  "createdAt": "2021-02-18T22:13:06.111Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-05-17T14:35:09.540Z",
  "archived": false,
  "associations": {
    "deals": {
      "results": [
        {
          "id": "5230410841",
          "type": "company_to_deal"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "dealdata": [
    {
      "id": "5230410841",
      "properties": {
        "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2021-05-13T14:00:33.101Z",
        "hs_object_id": "5230410841",
        "hubspot_owner_id": "52200226"
      },
      "associations": {
        "line items": {
          "results": [
            {
              "id": "1468189759",
              "type": "deal_to_line_item"
            },
            {
              "id": "1468189760",
              "type": "deal_to_line_item",
              "lineitemsdata": []
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "DealOwner": [
    {
      "id": "52200226",
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "firstName": "Bob"
    }
  ],
  "NetSuiteCustomerID": 1745
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Item inside object is called a `property`. If you (for some reason) have to include the property, but don't want it to have any value you can either set it's value to `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: In this case this is not so straight forward as the property is deep nested within an object that is itself within an array.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I'm going to get criticized for this, but here is a quick and dirty way of removing this specific problem through string replacement. The 'right' way would be to break down your json into separte objects until you get to the level where the offending object lives, remove it, then rebuild it all back. For what it's worth, here's an alternative to that

```js
let json = {
  "id": "5399286500",
  "properties": {
    "state": "AB",
    "website": null,
    "zip": "T3B5Y9"
  },
  "createdAt": "2021-02-18T22:13:06.111Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-05-17T14:35:09.540Z",
  "archived": false,
  "associations": {
    "deals": {
      "results": [{
        "id": "5230410841",
        "type": "company_to_deal"
      }]
    }
  },
  "dealdata": [{
    "id": "5230410841",
    "properties": {
      "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2021-05-13T14:00:33.101Z",
      "hs_object_id": "5230410841",
      "hubspot_owner_id": "52200226"
    },
    "associations": {
      "line items": {
        "results": [{
            "id": "1468189759",
            "type": "deal_to_line_item"
          },
          {
            "id": "1468189760",
            "type": "deal_to_line_item",
            "lineitemsdata": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  "DealOwner": [{
    "id": "52200226",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "firstName": "Bob"
  }],
  "NetSuiteCustomerID": 1745
}

json = JSON.stringify(json)
let strstart = json.indexOf('"lineitemsdata":[]');
let commapos = json.lastIndexOf(',', strstart);
json = json.substr(0, commapos) + " " + json.substr(commapos + 1);
json = json.replace('"lineitemsdata":[]', '');
json = JSON.parse(json)
console.log(json)
```

Comment: I was thinking something simple just like this (a simple find and replace). While not elegant, it works for my use case. However, I can't use the 'let JSON = ' section on the first line as the JSON record contents will vary.
Is there any way around that?

Comment: How does the json data get to your code? The JavaScript you want to inject needs to get a reference to the json, modify it and return the new json.

Comment: I am using Celigo, an IPASS system (similar to Boomi) so the way Celigo has it, you can just inject a javascript code prior to a 'step' in the transformation occurring. I can probably take this code to them and see if they can let me know how to reference each json 'record'

Comment: @Abrow - sounds good. As a note, this code assumed the JSON would be provided as an object (parsed) and the first thing I did was convert it into a string for the search/replace. Then at the end, converting the edited string back into an object. Not sure if your real life scenario will deliver the JSON as an object (most likely) or a string, but just an FYI. Not sure how else to help - if this solved your question, pls mark it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to strip any empty lineitems arrays from your json.
Assuming the reference to your record is `json`

```
for(dealIdx in json.dealdata) {
    for (resultIdx in json.dealdata[dealIdx].associations["line items"].results) {
        let lineItemsData = json.dealdata[dealIdx].associations["line items"].results[resultIdx].lineitemsdata
        if (lineItemsData != undefined && lineItemsData.length === 0 ) {
            delete json.dealdata[dealIdx].associations["line items"].results[resultIdx].lineitemsdata
        }
    }
}
```